# Do you think it is a good idea to stretch background images and add blur to keep file size low?

Tags: html, image, css

I'm using jpg and have more than 20 full screen images on each page and needed to save on file size so I shrank them to 480 x 300 and gave them all a 2px blur. The resolution looks fine to me because the blur hides it.

My question is, is it a good idea to stretch images to that extent?

Comment: No code, no example, no fiddle. Hard to understand. Too broad in answers. Primary opinion answers...

Comment: Sorry first time on stackoverflow, I will make a fiddle now :)

Comment: Ok, and read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask that's very useful. Welcome to stackoverflow :)

Comment: Thankyou, I will read that! Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/Jpharrison/wsu0vgq9/embedded/result/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No not at all. Use image sprites to reduce the http request or you can optimize the file size with online image optimizer or some automation task runner for example.

List of sites :

```
1. http://www.creativebloq.com/design/image-compression-tools-1132865. 
2.http://compressnow.com/

Task runner :
1. Grunt
2. Gulp
```

by optimizing images you can reduce file size without compromising image quality.

Comment: Thank you, I compressed all my images and they lost a small amount of quality but I got to keep the size as well as only going a few kb above my original shrinking attempt. I'll accept your answer!